# How do I open a specific port on OS X Yosemite from the command line?

Tags: macos, command, port, osx-yosemite

I cannot seem to find anywhere how to open a specific port on OS X Yosemite. I understand that I can use 'Little Snitch' in order to open a port, but I would love to do it from the command line.

This is for a Firewall port.

Comment: What do you mean by opening specific port? Like changing firewall rule to allow trafic on port?

Comment: Yes, if I go to my firewall in the system preferences, there is not option for a specific port... Only for applications. I need to open port 9050 so I can set my safari to send requests through Tor

Comment: This may help https://rolfje.wordpress.com/2014/05/10/open-a-port-in-osx-mavericks-firewall/

Comment: I actually tried that (without loading (last step)) and it didn't work. So I loaded it and rebooted and still no success... I use https://check.torproject.org to check if it works.

Comment: Hi @Wir3d_Gh0st same problem here. In my case I have completely disabled the firewall. Still no ports other than 80, 443 can be accessed, even though some process is listening.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142778/how-to-open-a-specific-port-in-firewall-os-x-10-9-4 ; there are yosemite answers there

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Apple SE.